# Java passing iterators to new Objects and returning them

Tags: java, list, object, iterator

I have created an object where I pass a string and a long value to it , currently I am adding the values to my Object so I can then add it to a list like so:

```
List myList;
ImageObject io;

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
  io = new ImageObject("String", i);
  myList.add(io);
  }
```

This is what the object currently looks like:

```
public final class ImageObject<name, time>
    {
    public String name = "";
    public long time = 0;


    public ImageObject(Object o)
        {
        // Think I need something here, but im not sure what!
        }

    public ImageObject(String name, long time)
        {
        this.name = name;
        this.time = time;
        }

    public long getTime()
        {
        return this.time;
        }
```

And this is how I would like to retrieve it:

```
    {
    ImageObject io;
    Iterator i = lstPageImages.iterator();

    while(i.hasNext())
        {
        io = new ImageObject(i.next());
        log.printDebug("name: "+io.name+" time: "+io.time);
        }
    }
```

Does anybody have any ideas? Many thanks in advance.

trscookie.

Comment: There is no reason to make your image object generic and if you don't know what kind of an object you are passing there is not much you can do with it right away. What type of objects does your 1stPageImages collection hold?

Comment: Hi, cheers for the speedy response, its not that Im trying to make the object generic, I just wasnt sure how to pass the value from the iterator back to the ImageObject in order for my class to recognise it again like so: io = new ImageObject(i.next());
So I could then go on to call the class back up, like so: log.printDebug("name: "+io.name+" time: "+io.time);

Comment: Well what kinds of objects are in your lstPageImages list?

Comment: ah sorry, just strings: private List lstPageImages = new ArrayList<String>(); Ah just realised, do I need to change that to reflect:   io = new ImageObject("String", i);
  myList.add(io);

Comment: So, just to make sure I understand what you're asking, you want to take an `ArrayList` of `Strings`, and use those `Strings` to create new `ImageObjects`, putting them into `myList`?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, Think I came up with a similar solution:

```
private List lstPageImages = new ArrayList<ImageObject>();
...
io = (ImageObject)i.next();
            log.printDebug("name: "+io.name+" time: "+io.time);
```

Cheers for your help :D